# How to subtract two date and value will be stored as number(int)?

Tags: mysql

how to subtract two dates and value will be stored as interger,
like

```
int a=returndate - issuedate;
```

here (a) will be number of days.

like

```
int a=24-12-2010 - 12-12-2010;
```

here a is 12;

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [DATEDIFF(expr1,expr2)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)

Answer (score 1):

use `timestamp` for this

```
$a=strtotime(24-12-2010) - strtotime(12-12-2010); 
date('m',$a);//gives number of days
```

for mysql use `DATEDIFF`

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)? Does it suit what you want?